# Extending asp:controlParameter for use with FileUpload control

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, objectdatasource

Thanks in advance.

Is it possible to extend the `asp:controlParameter` control within an objectDatasource control to accommodate the `asp:fileUpload` control and return a base64 string of the posted file.

for example I would like to be able to do this (key area to note is the insert parameter):

```
<asp:listview runat="server" datasourceID="objDS">
 <insertTemplate>
  <asp:fileupload id="fu" runat="server" />
  <asp:button id="submit" runat="server" text="Upload" commandName="INSERT" />
 </insertTemplate>
</asp:listview>

<asp:objectDatasource id="objDS" runat="server" ...>
 <insertParameters>
  <asp:fileuploadControlParameter controlID="fu" type="string" name="base64" />
 </insertParameters>
</asp:objectDatasource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's become apparent I've been approaching this the wrong way, I've simply extended the `asp:fileupload` control that allows me to bind the new property of base64 to the existing `asp:parameter` control of the `objectDatasource`.

```
Public Class fupload
    Inherits FileUpload

    Public ReadOnly Property base64 As String
        Get
            Return encodeBase64()
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function encodeBase64() As String
        Dim iLen As Integer = MyBase.PostedFile.ContentLength
        Dim btArr As Byte() = New Byte(iLen - 1) {}
        MyBase.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(btArr, 0, iLen)
        Dim b64Str As String = String.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}",
                                             MyBase.PostedFile.ContentType,
                                             Convert.ToBase64String(btArr))
        Return b64Str
    End Function
End Class
```

example usage:

```
<asp:listview runat="server" datasourceID="objDS">
 <insertTemplate>
  <asp:fileupload id="fu" runat="server" base64='<%# bind("base64")' />
  <asp:button id="submit" runat="server" text="Upload" commandName="INSERT" />
 </insertTemplate>
</asp:listview>

<asp:objectDatasource id="objDS" runat="server" ...>
 <insertParameters>
  <asp:Parameter type="string" name="base64" />
 </insertParameters>
</asp:objectDatasource>
```